# Unity - cant get objects to vibrate/hover in place?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

Ok, I have a bunch of cubes that I just need to vibrate/shake slowly in space as if hovering almost. I first tried using a particle emitter with noise but couldnt get the movement part. I am now trying by attaching a script to each object:

```
 float speed = 1.0f; //how fast it shakes
    float amount = 1.0f;
   public  Vector2 startingPos;

    void Awake()
    {
        startingPos.x = transform.position.x;
        startingPos.y = transform.position.y;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        float newx = startingPos.x + (Mathf.Sin(Time.time * speed) * amount);
        float newy = startingPos.y + (Mathf.Sin(Time.time * speed) * amount);

        transform.position = new Vector3(newx, newy, transform.position.z);

    }
```

With this the cubes disappear entirely. Ive looked on the forums to no avail - what can I do to make the cubes just vibrate/hover in place?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you'd use a package such as [LeanTween](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/leantween-3595) to handle your transitions/animations, at least in simple, small-scale cases like this.

Essentially, the process is this:

```
On Start:
    store 'starting' position

On Enabled:
    Run DoHover

On DoHover:
    Pick random offset within radius (Random.insideUnitCircle() * radius)
    LeanTween current transform to startingPos + offset over timeDelay
    Set LeanTween.OnComplete to run DoHover
```

---

If you're determined not to use a 3rd-party package to manage your tweening, you can try this (I use 3D scenes, but you should be able to flatten it easily):

```
    private const float threshold = 0.02f;

    private Vector3 startingPos;
    private Vector3 destinationPos;
    private Vector3 velocity;
    public float radius = 0.1f;
    public float minTimeDelay = 0.1f;
    public float maxTimeDelay = 0.3f;

    private void Start() {
        startingPos = destinationPos = transform.position;
    }


    // This is a 'physics' frame update
    public void FixedUpdate() {

        if ( Vector3.Distance(transform.position, destinationPos) < threshold ) {
            // Pick new destination and speed
            destinationPos = startingPos + Random.insideUnitSphere * radius;
            velocity = (destinationPos - transform.position) / Random.Range(minTimeDelay, maxTimeDelay);
        }

        // Move toward destination
        transform.position += velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    }
```

Comment: Id really like to avoid using external packages since I already had iTween installed, and only need it in this instance. Do you have any code examples of the shake without an external package?

Comment: You could certainly go about writing your own tweening code, probably in a coroutine, but I would definitely recommend you stick with a 3pp package.  iTween is fine if you prefer it, LeanTween is much more in the C# style.  I'll see if I can come up with something sans middleware.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this today using three stacked Sin waves; it's simple and gives a nice hovering-randomly-around-a-circle effect and doesn't require keeping track of where the object is/has been:

```html
transform.position.x = originalPosition.x + hoverSpeed * (
    Mathf.Sin(Time.time / 3) 
    + Mathf.Sin(Time.time / 7) 
    + Mathf.Sin(Time.time / 11)
    );

transform.position.y = originalPosition.y + hoverSpeed * (
    Mathf.Sin(Time.time / 2) 
    + Mathf.Sin(Time.time / 5) 
    + Mathf.Sin(Time.time / 13)
    );
```

I also start the object at originalPosition and gradually move outward by starting hoverSpeed at zero and doing:

```html
hoverSpeed = Mathf.Clamp(hoverSpeed + Time.deltaTime, 0, hoverMaxSpeed);
```